# Getting value of Dispatch in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement an account verification via the twilio api where it texts a user a code and it should set the state of `generatedCode` to that value, but i am having a difficult time getting that value of the dispatch. If i do a simple `await` with axios call it works fine, but not so much with a dispatch

**action:**

```
export const attemptRegisterVerify = (phone) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(registerVerifyBegin());
  await postRegisterVerifyPhone(phone)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(registerVerifySuccess(res.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(registerVerifyFail(error));
    });
};
```

**handleVerification:**

```
const handleVerification = async (values) => {
    const { email, phone } = values;
    setModal(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/register/check-duplicate',
        {
          email,
          phone,
        }
      );

      if (response.data.success) {
        switch (response.data.message) {
          case 0:
            try {
              const response = await dispatch(
                attemptRegisterVerify({ to: phone })
              );
              console.log(response);
              // if (response.data.success) {
              //   setGeneratedCode(response.data.message);
              //   console.log(generatedCode);
              // } else {
              //   console.log(response.data.message);
              // }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
            break;

          case 1:
            console.log('Email Address already in use.');
            break;
          case 2:
            console.log('Phone number already in use.');
            break;
          case 3:
            console.log('Email and Phone in use.');
            break;
        }
      } else {
        console.log(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

The console.log(response) returns `undefined`. Is there a way for it to wait until that dispatch is completed, then proceed?

---

```
export const attemptRegisterVerify = (phone) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(registerVerifyBegin());
  await postRegisterVerifyPhone(phone)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(registerVerifySuccess(res.data));
      return res.data; // return console.log(res.data) works
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(registerVerifyFail(error));
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little? You say "console.log(response)" but you never do that in your code anywhere? And you have a `handleVerification` function that's not referenced from your action method? I'm having trouble putting together where your actual problem is based on this example.

Comment: What  does the function postRegisterVerifyPhone does it return anything?

Comment: @LoicH `const postRegisterVerifyPhone = (phone) => api.post('/auth/register/verify-phone', phone);`

Comment: @ChrisTavares I console.log(response) right after the dispatch to see what the response is but it returns `undefined`. It's not referenced in the action creator because its part of the RegisterForm to verify that the user email and phone doesn't already exist. If it doesn't exist I want to dispatch the registerVerifyPhone action to send the code to the user.

Comment: Is it even necessary to have the phone verification as a dispatch if im not storing any state? Should I just do a simple axios call at the component level?

Comment: How about this ? 

async function postRegisterVerifyPhone = (phone) {

  let res = await api.post('/auth/register/verify-phone', phone);

  let data = res.data;
  return data
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispatch returns what you return in the function call. In the case of an async thunk, it'll return `Promise<void>` by default unless you return something.

If in your `attemptRegisterVerify` thunk, if you add `return 'test'` to the end of it, then your `console.log(response)` would log `'test'`.

In a non-thunk, the return value of the dispatch would be the action that was generated.

Comment: So that worked, I've added additional code to the bottom of the OP with what I know have, but the `console.log(response)` within the handleVerification function still returns undefined, but if i `console.log(res.data)` within the promise of the action i see it in the console.

Comment: You have to return the `await`postRegisterVerifyPhone` otherwise you're returning nothing from `attemptRegisterVerify`. Functions don't auto return anything.